# is it possible to replace all string in a list to its equivalent uppercase using forEach() method?

Tags: java, list, collections

I'm trying out ways to replace all string in a list to its equivalent uppercase. I know that this is possible using replaceAll() method. However, I'm just wondering if it is also possible using the forEach() method?

```
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("justin", "nancy", "cooc", "amy", "david");
list2.replaceAll(s -> s.toUpperCase());

list2.forEach();
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `forEach` to affect content of your list just like you shouldn't use enhanced for-loop that way. `replaceAll` is correct way here (that is why it was introduced in Java 8).

Comment: I don't think it's actually possible for `forEach` to do it.

Comment: `list2.replaceAll(String::toUpperCase);` is the best way.

Comment: @LouisWasserman It is possible (at least for this specific case) `list2.forEach(s -> list2.set(list2.indexOf(s), s.toUpperCase()));` but still it is very bad idea.

Comment: @Pshemo It works even if there are repetitions.

Comment: @PaulBoddington but not if there is parallelism https://ideone.com/tgt4ld

Comment: @Pshemo `List.indexOf()` should come with text like this: *!!!WARNING!!! Very bad for performance. Use only in extreme emergencies. !!!WARNING!!! In case of duplicate elements, will only return index of first element. !!!WARNING!!! Stay away !!!DANGER!!!* That would save lots of people from doing bad code like that. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to replace all string in a list to its equivalent uppercase using forEach() method?

Yes<sup>1</sup>, if you combine it with an [`IntStream.range(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-). Something like,

```
IntStream.range(0, list2.size()).forEach(x -> 
        list2.set(x, list2.get(x).toUpperCase()));
```

<sup>1<sub>However, your current solution is more efficient.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can new anothor list like this:

```
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("justin", "nancy", "cooc", "amy", "david");
List<String> list1 = list2.stream().map(e -> e.toUpperCase()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```